# MySQL - any advantage using "LIMIT 1" with an aggregate function like COUNT or SUM?

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL, is there any advantage (performance or otherwise) using "LIMIT 1" with an aggregate function like COUNT or SUM?

So for instance, is:

```
SELECT COUNT(colA), COUNT(colB) FROM data_table LIMIT 1;
```

Better than:

```
SELECT COUNT(colA), COUNT(colB) FROM data_table;
```

Other posts I've found haven't considered the aggregate functions.

Comment: Please don't downvote legitimate questions with perfectly acceptable content. As Gordon's excellent answer has stated, the optimizer knows this, but I wanted feedback on this. I had searched for this answer and couldn't find anything relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no reason to include `LIMIT 1`.  An aggregation query with no `GROUP BY` always returns exactly one row.  The optimizer knows this, so `LIMIT` provides zero additional information.

In fact, by putting a `LIMIT` in, you are being a bit misleading, because you are suggesting that it *could* return more than one row.  At some later point, someone might ask "where is the `GROUP BY`?" or something like that.